# I cannot modify the dictionary value when enumerating an array consist of dictionary elements

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

```
var files = NSMutableArray()
...
for (var i = 0; i < files.count; i++) {
    var f = files[i] as [String: AnyObject]
    f["selected"] = true
}
```

When I debug the code, the "selected" property of f is set correctly. but the corresponding element in the files remains unchanged. Why? Thanks.

Comment: try var f = files[i] as NSMutableDictionary instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is going on with using an NSMutableArray here... but perhaps it's working like a value type instead of a reference type. Try replacing the item in the array with the modified version.

```
files.replaceObjectAtIndex(i, withObject: f)
```

Place it after you make your modification.

```
var files = NSMutableArray()
//...
for (var i = 0; i < files.count; i++) {
    var f = files[i] as! [String: AnyObject]
    f["selected"] = true
    files.replaceObjectAtIndex(i, withObject: f)
}
```

If you were using a swift array type, something like this should work instead.

```
var files = [[String: AnyObject]]()

//...
for (var i = 0; i < files.count; i++) {
    var f = files[i] as [String: AnyObject]
    f["selected"] = true
    files[i] = f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason corresponding elements of file is not changing is that you are not modifying it at all you are just altering values of **var f** inside the loop.

Try this code:

```
    var files = [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]()
    // Probably you are trying to make array of dictionary objects 
    for var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++ {
        files[i]["selected"] = true
    }
```